# Solving $y''+9y = t^2e^{3t}$ by the method of undetermined coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In order to solve

$$y''+9y = t^2e^{3t}+6$$

I broke up it in:

$$y''+9y = t^2e^{3t}$$
and

$$y''+9y = 6$$

the one that interest me is the $y''+9y = t^2e^{3t}$. What should be my guess? I tried:

$$Y = At^2e^{3t}\implies Y' = A(t^2\cdot 3\cdot e^{3t}+2te^{3t})\implies$$
$$Y''= A(2t\cdot 3e^{3t}+t^2\cdot 9e^{3t}+2e^{3t}+6te^{3t}$$

Then the equation becomes:

$$A(2t\cdot 3e^{3t}+t^2\cdot 9e^{3t}+2e^{3t}+6te^{3t}+9(At^2e^{3t}) = t^2e^{3t}$$

but how should I group the terms in the left to equate to the ones in the right? First of all, is my guess right?

Comment: Do you know Laplace transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the RHS term has the form $P_n(t)e^{\alpha t}$, where $P_n$ is a $n$-degree polynomial, and if $\alpha$ is not a solution of the characteristic equation (in your example, the characteristic equation is $\lambda^2+9=0$, for which $3$ is not a solution, then the particular solution of the differential equation has the form $Q_n(t)e^{\alpha t}$, where $Q_n$ is a $n$-degree polynomial.

So you should try with $Q_n(t)=at^2+bt+c$.

Going further:
\begin{align*}
\bar y&=(at^2+bt+c)e^{3t}\\
\bar y'&=(2at+b)e^{3t}+3(at^2+bt+c)e^{3t}\\
\bar y''&=2ae^{3t}+3(2at+b)e^{3t}+3(2at+b)e^{3t}+9(at^2+bt+c)e^{3t}
\end{align*}

Substituting:

$$
2ae^{3t}+3(2at+b)e^{3t}+3(2at+b)e^{3t}+9(at^2+bt+c)e^{3t}+9(at^2+bt+c)e^{3t}=t^2e^{3t},
$$

which yelds:

$$
\begin{cases}
9a+9a=18a=1\\
6a+6a+9b+9b=12a+18b=0\\
2a+3b+3b+9c+9c=2a+6b+18c=0
\end{cases}
$$

The solution is

$$
\begin{cases}
a=1/18\\
b=-1/27\\
c=1/162
\end{cases}
$$

Then your particular solution is

$$
\bar y=\left(\frac{1}{18}t^2-\frac{1}{27}t+\frac{1}{162}\right)e^{3t}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving this is using Laplace transform:

$$y''(t)+9y(t)=t^2e^{3t}+6$$

Laplace transform:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[y''(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}+9\cdot\mathcal{L}_t\left[y(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[t^2e^{3t}\right]_{(\text{s})}+6\cdot\mathcal{L}_t\left[1\right]_{(\text{s})}$$

Now, use:

1. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[y''(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\text{s}^2\text{Y}(\text{s})-\text{s}y(0)-y'(0)$$
2. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[y(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\text{Y}(\text{s})$$
3. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[t^2e^{3t}\right]_{(\text{s})}=\frac{2}{\left(\text{s}-3\right)^3}$$
4. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[1\right]_{(\text{s})}=\frac{1}{\text{s}}$$

So, we get:

$$\text{s}^2\text{Y}(\text{s})-\text{s}y(0)-y'(0)+9\text{Y}(\text{s})=\frac{2}{\left(\text{s}-3\right)^3}+\frac{6}{\text{s}}$$

Solving for $\text{Y}(\text{s})$:

$$\text{Y}(\text{s})=\frac{\frac{2}{\left(\text{s}-3\right)^3}+\frac{6}{\text{s}}+\text{s}y(0)+y'(0)}{9+\text{s}^2}$$

Using inverse Laplace transform, we get:

$$y(t)=\frac{108+e^{3t}\left(1-3t\right)^2+\cos(3t)\left(162y(0)-109\right)+\sin(3t)\left(1+54y'(0)\right)}{162}$$

Answer (score 0):

In your final equation if you cancel out the $e^{3t}$'s you have a polynomial equation which won't be satisfied for all $t$, meaning you don't have a solution.  A better Ansatz is to suppose your solution is of the form $(At^2+Bt+C)e^{3t}$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the undetermined coefficients method to solve the question, the right hand side contains the  known functions, you must take the following form in particular solution
$$y_{p1}=At^2+Bt+C$$
$$y_{p_2}=Ee^{3t}$$
$$y_{p3}=F$$
 when you multiply  the first two  solutions, some constants multiplied together can make it one, so we get the following  from which we get the solution
$$y_p=e^{3t}(k_1t^2+k_2t+k_3)+k_4$$
differentiate the solution twice and substitute in the D.E to get the values of constants